# Data assigned to a global Vue object from a function is "deleted" after exiting the func

Tags: javascript, function, global, variable-assignment

Im assigning data into a global (Vue) object
it is going in (checked it on debbuger)
but going back to its prev value whn exiting the func.

What should I do to make it stay there?

```
"use strict";

var App = 
{
    debugMode: 2,//0=no, 1=yes, 2=special deep debug :-(~)
    serverApi: '../../Server/CrmAPI.php',
    navTemplate: new Vue({el: '#menuTemplate',

        data: {
            objectName: "",
            brandName: "CRM"
        }
    }),
    currentObject: null // each time containes a different object that currently active by user selection


}


function navigateMainNav( selectedObj )
{
    var objectName = selectedObj; //try 1
    window.App.navTemplate.objectName = objectName; //try 2
    App.navTemplate.data.objectName = objectName; // try 3


    window.location.href = "../html/templates/navTemplate.html" ; // load html

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want global data inside of your Vue application, consider using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

It basically is a state manager and lets you put data into a global Vuex storage where it can be accessed from all of your components.

Also, having your global stuff in a Vuex store prevents you from poisoning your global namespace inside of your js scripts. You should check it out, it's not as hard as they make it look like! ;)